# Wait for async recursive function to complete before proceeding to next line of code

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, puppeteer

I am trying to wait for a recursive function to fully complete before proceeding to next line of code.  I am using PuppeteerJS to look for an item on a page and if the item does not exist, after 3 seconds reload the page and try again.  I need this function to complete before proceeding. Simple code example of what I am trying to achieve below.

```
(async () => {
    await waitForThisToFinish() // Wait for this function no matter how long it takes
    console.log("Don't log until function has completed")
})()

async function waitForThisToFinish() {
    try {
        await findItemOnPage()  //function times out after 3 seconds
    }
    catch (ex) {
        // If Item is not found after 3 seconds an error is thrown.
        // Catch error and reload page to see if item has been loaded and look again.
        waitForThisToFinish() //recursive call
    }
}
```

Currently, if the item is not found on first try, the error is thrown and the recursion starts successfully.  However, code execution continues and does not wait for the function to complete successfully.

Is there a way to make 'catch' not resolve? Do I need to return a promise from the waitForThisToFinish() function? How would that work with recursion? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to await the `waitForThisToFinish` if you actually want to wait for it.

Comment: Better to use a loop that you break out of when successful than recursion here.  There's really no need for recursion.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the quick and simple solutions.  Both of these suggestions did the trick individually.  Is there any reason/benefit of doing one vs. the other?

Comment: I offered some rationale for the looping solution in my answer below.  I also made several other suggestions on the looping (checking for non-permanent error and implementing back-off on the retry).

Comment: `return await  waitForThisToFinish()` in the catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a loop that you break out of when successful because then there is no build-up of resources in any way (like promises) and you can call your function an infinite number of times if required without stressing resource usage.

```
async function waitForThisToFinish() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            let val = await findItemOnPage()
            // use break or return here to break out of the loop
            return val;
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log("still waiting and trying again")
        }
    }
}
```

---

In addition, you also should make several additional changes:

1. Check the actual error to make sure it's the type of error that can be fixed by retry (such as a timeout).  If it's a permanent error, you will retry forever.
2. Implement a delay before retrying to avoid causing avalanche failures on the server-side and to avoid server blocking from rate limiting.
3. Implement a progressive back-off in the delay.

Since you generally don't want to write code that hammers a server (by repeatedly making the same request over and over again in rapid succession) whenever there's an error because this can cause avalanche server failures where a small problem turns into a big problem very quickly, you should probably implement a delay before trying again that backs off into a longer delay the longer the issue persists.

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}


async function waitForThisToFinish() {
    let waitTime = 100;
    while (true) {
        try {
            let val = await findItemOnPage()
            // use break or return here to break out of the loop
            return val;
        } catch (ex) {
            // Should also check if the actual error is one that is likely
            // temporary.  Otherwise, you may loop forever on a permanent error
            console.log("still waiting and trying again")
            // implement super simple backoff (there are much more elegant algorithms available)
            await delay(waitTime);
            waitTime += 300;
        }
    }
}
```